# How to fix "Run Configuration Error: [No Rails found in SDK]"?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, intellij-idea, rubymine

I am looking at a Rails project which I would like to be able to work with using IntelliJ 15.0.3 (full version) under Ubuntu 15.10.

The project builds with "bundle install".  Rails run from the command line using "rails s".    IntelliJ (and RubyMine 8.0.3) does not want to launch Rails but complains with "[No Rails found in SDK]".

I have tried the default ruby in Ubuntu.  I have tried compiling Ruby 2.3.0 and installing it in my own home folder.   There is a rails binary next to the ruby binary.  The gem is installed.  I cannot use jruby for this project as gems with native extensions are needed.

I am suspecting I may be hitting a bug in the Ruby plugin.  Is there a workaround or similar I can use?

Comment: After quite a bit of experimentation, I ended up with installing a bare Ruby 2.3.0 in my home folder (`./configure --prefix=$HOME/...`) without any gems at all and told IntelliJ to use that.  Then IntelliJ suggested installing missing gems, and eventually it ended up with an SDK approved to have Rails.  This has too much magic to my taste.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I didn't need to reinstall any version of ruby, but I did have to go into

RubyMine -> Preferences -> Language & Frameworks -> Ruby SDK Gems

then from there reselect the version of ruby stated in my gemfile.

Comment: For me it didn't work.