# No Rails found in SDK on Sierra

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I have seen:

[How to fix "Run Configuration Error: [No Rails found in SDK]"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583060/how-to-fix-run-configuration-error-no-rails-found-in-sdk)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658326/rubymine-kept-telling-me-no-rails-found-in-sdk

[No rails found in sdk intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013352/no-rails-found-in-sdk-intellij)
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206714535-No-Rails-found-in-SDK

I have:

```
RubyMine 2016.2.3
Build #RM-162.1812.23, built on September 5, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b343 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
MacOs 10.12.1 (16B2555)
```

I tried setting it up as normal by choosing the ruby version with a green check, hitting apply: 
[image]

Also I tried running:

```
gem update --system
gem install rails
```

This doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't, update your X-code installation by running:

```
xcode-select --install
```

then rebuild all your gems by running:

```
gem pristine --all
```

Updating to sierra messes up with your dev environment. The above worked for me.